# VSCode Jupyter notebook loses syntax highlighting once saving the file

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, syntax-highlighting

I'm using a Jupyter file on VS Code and the syntax highlighting seems to work until I save the file for the first time. After that, it deactivates (see before & after pics). I don't have Dependency Analytics installed, the bottom right of the cell says "Python", I've tried reinstalling intellicode, jupyter, and pylance extensions. Does anyone know what is going on?

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKlhT.png)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9BfI.png)

I've looked through other SO posts and haven't found any solutions that worked. Some specifics:

- Python 3.11.2
- VS Code v 1.75.1
- Windows 10

Comment: looks like you still actually have syntax highlighting, just a different presentation.

Comment: it should not say" Python" but "Magic Python" (the default syntax interpreter for VS CODE). Should you probably reinstall it? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=magicstack.MagicPython

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

- Add the following two settings in the *settings.json*

  ```
  "editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": true,    
  "python.languageServer": "Pylance",
  ```
- You can use the shortcut key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to switch the theme to see if the syntax highlighting has changed

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I added those two rules to my user settings JSON file. It did not seem to make any difference. Any other ideas?

Comment: What about the workspace *settings.json*? Does changing the theme change anything?

Comment: I'm not seeing any option in my CTRL+SHIFT+P dropdown for 'Preferences: Open Workspace Settings (JSON). The only JSON settings options available are 'User' and 'Default'.

Comment: Sorry for not being able to reproduce your problem. If you have the complete steps, you can head over to [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/new/choose) to submit your issue.